# Silverlight converter to convert an object to a string and back

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I have an Address object in my model which has 6 address lines as separate properties.  In my Silverlight view I want this to be displayed in a multiline text box and to be updated using databinding.

The View is linked to a ViewModel which has an Address property which is always set.  My first thought was to use a ValueConverter which was initially fine as it could take an Address object and pass back a string which is displayed.

My problem arises when I want to ConvertBack the string.  I wish to update the existing Address object but cannot find a way to do this.  I think you can pass back a new Address object but this is not what I want to happen.

I am on the right track here or is there a better method than using a ValueConverter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost on the right track here! You are right in your observation that the `ConvertBack` method would need to create a new Address instance. You cannot obtain a reference back to the original address in your converter, the binding framework does not permit this kind of tight coupling.

How about using MVVM? create a ViewModel that exposes / adapts your Address as a string, basically performing the role of your value converter. When the `TwoWay` binding updates this string property, your ViewModel can then update the Address that it adapts.

Comment: I am using MVVM but got sidelined into thinking about converters.  My reason for using a converter was to reduce the amount of code required (i.e. no need for extra properties on view models) and aid re-use in other views (i.e. simply specify a converter in the view whenever required).  This doesn't look possible though so I'll use your method and try and make it as clean as possible.  Thanks.